# Flutter - how to return data from WorkManager to main isolate?

Tags: flutter

I can’t see any mention in the WorkManager docs about how to return data from a background isolate to the main UI isolate.
What is recommended best practice?

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue until I used [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) to save the result/data from `WorkManager` and on the main UI isolate I periodically call `sharedPreferences.reload()` to load the latest values. Then I retrieve the data stored by `WorkManager`. Hope this helps.